# How do i make the bot mention someone just by typing out the user's name without the tag

Tags: python, discord.py

for example:

> me: -mention LOL
>
> > Bot: @LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `member: discord.Member` as an required argument.

If you want to mention a user you have to use `member.mention`.

**Here is an example code:**

```py
@client.command() # Or whatever you use
async def mention(ctx, member: discord.Member = None): 
    if member == None: # If no argument was passed
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention) # Mention the author of the command
    else:
        await ctx.send(member.mention) # Mention the member
```

**Here is how it looks like:**

[image]

Comment: is there a way to have the member argument to be optional? because I want it to mention the person but when there is no argument I want it to mention me

Comment: @Unexperienceddude69 Yes, but that would require some more code. The docs can help. I'm also wondering right now why you revoked my answer. Is it now because you want to know more? That's not how it works...

Comment: oh sorry about that